# Error Message in vs2015 enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis-2012

my machine has VS2015 enterprise installed with following settings:

`Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01590
SQL Server Analysis Services   14.0.806.134
SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.61707.300
SQL Server Integration Services   Version 14.0.800.90
SQL Server Reporting Services   14.0.806.134
SSDTDevPack.VSPackage   1.0
Web Essentials 2015.3   3.0.235`

While opening a DTSX file (SSIS package file), I got following error message->
[image: ErrorMessage]

What can be the reason for it?